# Leaflet geoJson layers hidden outside viewport

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map with a few layers on it.
Whenever layers are not in the viewport, they are hidden untill panning has completed:

Regular view with layers:

[image: Regular view]

Panning right, to show layers outside viewport:

[image: Panning]

Panning stopped:

[image: Panning stopped]

As illustrated above, the layers will first become visible once panning has stopped and mouse(finger) released.

I have tried the following, which didn't work

```
var map = L.map('map',{ bounceAtZoomLimits: false, removeOutsideVisibleBounds: false}).setView([40, 0], 2);
L.geoJson(mapData).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the solution was right in front of me

Adding the following will render the entire map:

```
var map = new L.Map('map');
map.getRenderer(map).options.padding = 100;
```

Solution found [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2814)